# Finding records in table 1 that do not exist in table 2 and returning all fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join

I have 2 tables like this

```
+------+-------+------+------+---------+
| NAME |SURNAME|DEPART| POST |EMPLOYEE#|
+------+-------+------+------+---------+
| JACK | LONDON| 111  |WRITER| 12345678|
|......|.......|......|......|.........|
+------+-------+------+------+---------+
```

and

```
+------+-------+------+------+---------+
| NAME |SURNAME|DEPART| POST |  LOGIN  |
+------+-------+------+------+---------+
| MARK | TWAIN | 222  |WRITER| MTWAIN  |
|......|.......|......|......|.........|
+------+-------+------+------+---------+
```

I need to find records in table 1 that do not exist in table 2, and return all fields for such records.

I use code like this...

```
SELECT name,depart FROM tb1 EXCEPT SELECT name,depart FROM table2
```

As expected the result is only 2 fields NAME,DEPART.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically, you can use `LEFT JOIN` on this. When a record on `Table1` doesn't find any matches on `Table2`, the result on the values of the columns on `Table2` will be *NULL*, so to filter out non matching values, add a condition which checks for *NULL* values on table2.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    Table1 a
        LEFT JOIN Table2 b
            ON a.name = b.name AND
                a.depart = b.depart
WHERE   b.Name IS NULL
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: maybe you mean b.Name IS NULL ?

Comment: what grammar do you mean? `:)`

Comment: someone edited my post ._. and fixed grammar and linguistic errors

Answer (score 1):

Assuming name, surname and depart are sufficient to uniquely identify people, try:

```
select t1.*
from tb1 t1
where not exists
(select 1
 from table2 t2
 where t1.name = t2.name and 
       t1.surname = t2.surname and 
       t1.depart = t2.depart)
```

Comment: btw, people are not unique. in corp can work name1 surname1 in department1, and name1 surname1 in department2. and they are different. but, thx.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from tb1
minus
select *
from tb2
```

Comment: Please add some more explanation to your solution.